# Calculation Odds Ratio and Relative risk for all the alleles in multi allelic locus like HLA?

Tags: r, statistics, bioinformatics

Is there any R package that can calculate Odds Ratio and Relative risk for all the alleles in multi allelic locus like HLA-A? I know I can do one by one for each allele but if there is any package it will be helpful to know. Or if anyone can suggest small code it will also be helpful

```
 Allele Control Case 

 1. A*01   116   17
 2. A*02   186   30 
 3. A*03     2    2 
 4. A*04     1    1 
 5. A*05     71   9 
 6. A*11     25   8
 7. A*12     10   5
```

In the above sample data I want to calculate Odds ratio and Relative risk for each allele (A*01, A*02, A*03 ...... A*12).

If we take first row the 2x2 contingency table would be

```
 Allele control case

 1. A*01 116 17  
 2. Others 295 55
```

Note: Others has a sum of all other remaining rows. Now let's create 2x2 contingency table:

```
M2 <- matrix(c(55,17, 295, 116), nrow = 2)
colnames(M2) <- c("Cases", "Controls")
rownames(M2) <- c("Others", "A*01")
```

Then calculate the odds ratio and relative risk using orr fun from mosaic package: `orr(M2,conf.level = 0.95, quiet = FALSE)`

**What I want is same calculation for each row vs all other remaining rows. Let me know if I am not clear**

Comment: So what precisely is the calculation you want to carry out. What is the desired value for the provided sample data?

Comment: Thanks MrFlick, I have added more information to the question. I hope now it makes it clear. Thanks

Comment: Use @ sign before username, so they get pinged, like this: @MrFlick

Answer (score 1):

This builds a binomial model. To get the the odds ratio one would exponetiate the coeeficitns. Adding `+0` to the formula  means there will be no reference level and you then get estimates for every factor level relative to an "expected" or Null value of 0, i.e. equal proportions of cases and controls. To get the relative risks, you should do a bit of searching to find the proper transformation.

```
dat <- read.table(text="Allele Control Case 
A*01 116   17
A*02 186   30 
A*03 2    2 
A*04 1    1 
A*05 71   9 
A*11 25   8
A*12 10   5", head=TRUE)

> glm(cbind(Case,Control)~Allele+0, binomial, data=dat)

Call:  glm(formula = cbind(Case, Control) ~ Allele + 0, family = binomial, 
    data = dat)

Coefficients:
AlleleA*01  AlleleA*02  AlleleA*03  AlleleA*04  AlleleA*05  AlleleA*11  
   -1.9204     -1.8245      0.0000      0.0000     -2.0655     -1.1394  
AlleleA*12  
   -0.6931  

Degrees of Freedom: 7 Total (i.e. Null);  0 Residual
Null Deviance:      273.6 
Residual Deviance: 2.109e-14    AIC: 37.66

> exp( coef(glm(cbind(Case,Control)~Allele+0, binomial, data=dat)))
AlleleA*01 AlleleA*02 AlleleA*03 AlleleA*04 AlleleA*05 AlleleA*11 
 0.1465517  0.1612903  1.0000000  1.0000000  0.1267606  0.3200000 
AlleleA*12 
 0.5000000
```

Comment: Please see the updated question and let me know if you can help. I guess what you have suggested is different from what I want. Thanks though.

Comment: Seems fairly simple to just loop over the rows and do the desired calculation. It may have seemed too simple for people and they may not have taken it upon them to write a package. (Rather like a homework task.) On the other hand , have you done any searching of the Bioconductor packages?